# How to change the aspect ratio of image and upload to Imgur?

Tags: javascript, html, css, imgur

I have a drop zone where you can drop or select images. And I am using a background-image property to display the image.

I am building a **post scheduler for Instagram** and the **API** requires an Image to have an aspect ratio between the range of **4:5 to 1.91:1**.

**So how do I change the aspect ratio of an image selected from the computer and upload it to imgur so it would have an aspect ratio between 4:5 to 1.91:1?**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily resize images according to your aspect ratio on paint software. If you want to maintain 4:5 ratio then your pixel calculation will be 800x1000. If you want to maintain 1.91:1 ratio then your pixel calculation will be 1200x628.
Moreover, for the Instagram post, you can use square images with 1080x1080 with no issues. Then you can upload to any image hosting site like Imgur, Imgbb, or flicker.

**Note:** **You can resize your image anywhere(canva, photoshop, photopea, etc.)**

Comment: I am developing a software and want to resize the image automatically not manually.